# Succes funcion not working after transfer parameter from class

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I create class. Everything work, but success function not redirect. Why?

```js
class Ajax {
  constructor(url, method, dataType, reDirect, alert) {
    this.url = url,
      this.method = method,
      this.dataType = dataType,
      this.reDirect = reDirect,
      this.alert = alert
  }

  getAJAX() {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.url,
      method: this.method,
      dataType: this.dataType,
      success: function(result) {
        window.location = this.reDirect
      },
      error: function(result) {
        alert(this.alert)
      }
    })
  }
}
```

This is how I call a method from the class:

```
const clearConf = new Ajax('/ConfigurationHistories/ClearList', 'GET', 'text', '/ConfigurationHistories/Index', 'Not clear list.')
clearConf.getAJAX()
```

Comment: `this` in the `success` handler function does not contain a reference to your `Ajax` class. You need to cache that outside of the handler or use an arrow function (assuming you don't need to support IE at all). See the duplicate for more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `this` is reassigned in the `success` function. Use an arrow function:

```
success: () => {
  window.location = this.reDirect;
}
```

Or use `bind`:

```
success: function() {
  window.location = this.reDirect;
}.bind(this);
```